# Spring: Is there a way to manually create a Bean from POST parameters, while still auto instantiating the instantiable ones?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, post

One of my post parameters passes a string that helps initialize one of the instance variable objects my Bean has, but I need a custom deserializer to do it because the parameter is a String. Is there a way to manually create a Bean from POST parameters? My bean has a lot of instance fields that can be instantiated manually from the POST parameters (let's say lots of String fields), so I'm still trying to take advantage of @ModelAttribute's ability to automatically map fields like Strings and ints. I just want a special case I can implement for some of the fields, like `Color` below.

My bean:

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private String className;
    private String schoolName;
    private String country;
    private Color color;
}

public class Color {
    private String name;
    private int r;
    private int g;
    private int b;

    public static Color fromString(String name) {
       Color color = new Color();
       color.name = name;
       // do some processing to initialize r, g, b based on name
    }
}
```

My JSP:

```
<form method="POST" action="/getTests">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="className">
<input type="text" name="schoolName">
<input type="text" name="country">
<input type="text" name="colorName">
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/getTests"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getTests(ModelMap modelMap, @ModelAttribute Test test) {
        System.out.println(test);
        modelMap.addAttribute("tests", tests);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

So I want to write something like this, that gets called before or after @ModelAttribute does its job of initializing `name`, `className`, `schoolName`, and `country`:

```
public class TestDeserializer {
    public class Test deserialize(Map<String, Object> requestMap) {
       Test test = new Test();
       String colorName = requestMap.get("colorName");
       if (colorName != null) {
           test.setColor(Color.fromString(colorname));
       }
       return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what do `r,g,b` depend on?

Comment: it's just a random example off the top of my head, i guess it depends on the color's name